# Netbeans/PHP "Project Sources directory is not empty."

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp

I store my PHP projects in my www folder within my WAMP folder and yesterday I accidentally deleted the www folder. I reinstalled the WAMP server and upgraded from version 2.5 to version 3.0.6 (I only include that information because prior to the version upgrade I haven't had these problems). Now whenever I try to create a new project in Netbeans and I choose the www folder for my "sources folder" it shows this error message at the bottom of the page:
 "Project Sources directory is not empty." 
It allows me to go ahead and create the project but it generates a bunch of code within it (presumably from the wamplangues and wampthemes folders that are sub-folders of the www folder). What do I need to do differently to make this work?

Comment: Did you choose **PHP Application** or **PHP Application with Existing Sources**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, WAMP has some directories under www directory.

Their intention is for you to create a directory for your project.

So, in Netbeans, your project directory should not be c:\wamp64\www (for Windows with Wamp 64 bits) but c:\wamp64\www\projectname

Then, through WAMP interface, you could easily add a Virtual Host (which should also be created in your hosts file... depending on your OS).

By the way... this is nor a PHP nor a Netbeans problem... ;)

Comment: Netbeans will need an empty directory to store the project... Which seems logical. 
C:\wamp64\www contains other "projects" like phpMyAdmin... so... it is not empty! ;)

Comment: @digiteeb, could you mark your question as anwered please?